# Convert string with underscores to number with one function call in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an interesting task for the job interview.

String with numbers and underscores must be converted to the number with just one native function call. This code will work only in Chrome.

```
someFunc('1_22_333') = 122333;
```

Does anyone know what this function is? Maybe this is one of the new features?

Comment: @KoshVery I've never known `parseInt` to *continue* parsing after it reaches an unparsable character like `_`.

Comment: @KoshVery parseInt('1_22_333') returns only 1

Comment: @Kosh Very, on my Mac OS Chrome (v78) `parseInt('1_22_333')` gives me 1, not the full number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a trick question? Chrome will convert 1_22_333 to 122333 without any function applied at all, because ES6 supports underscores in numbers by default.

If it's a string, however, `Number()`, `parseInt()`, and `parseFloat()` either fail with `NaN` or just give you a `1`, stopping at the first underscore.

There is one function that will do the trick, however: the dreaded `eval()`.

Comment: And `eval` did the job! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, @VLAZ, as a numeric literal is what I meant by "without any function applied at all".

Comment: @kshetline yeah, sorry, I missed the `eval` part. That would definitely treat it as a literal, so it's one option. I'm not really convinced on how useful this is as an interview question, though.

Comment: @VLAZ, yes, I definitely agree on the questionable quality of the question.

Answer (score 2):

> with just one native **function call**

Emphasis mine. If this is the exact requirement, then you can try to skirt the rules. [The answer from kshetline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58581325/) already shows you can use `eval` but if it was me who was giving the interview, I'd very much want people to *not* use `eval`. So, for me the *one* function call requirement can be fulfilled by using `replace`:

```js
function someFunc(arg) {
  return +arg.replace(/_/g, "")
}

console.log(someFunc('1_22_333'))
```

So, this is *one* call to [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) *operator*.

This is somewhat exploiting technicalities, however:

- The question never specifies *not* to use operators, it just says single function call. Since the requirement doesn't explicitly forbid non-function operations, then the operator is not outside the rules.
- `.replace` is also a *method* not a function, since it's a property of the String object. However, this is a bit more of a philosophical distinction - you can certainly point out that JS has a very loose distinction between methods and functions. All methods are simply *functions* that are attached to an object and (usually but not always) use the `this` context.

If that second point is contested, then feel free to bend the rules even harder - if a *method* won't cut it, then a method shouldn't count as part of the requirement for *one function call*. The same way the `+` operator doesn't count. So, in that case, this code should pass the requirement:

```js
function someFunc(arg) {
  var method = String.prototype.replace;
  var fn = method.bind(arg);
  return +fn(/_/g, "");
}

console.log(someFunc('1_22_333'))
```

I've broken it down for easier reasoning. You can also just write `+String.prototype.replace.bind(arg)(/_/g, "")`

- `String.prototype.replace` is not a function call, it's fetching a value of an object. In this case it's the `String` prototype but doesn't matter.
- [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) is a *method call*. If it doesn't count as a function, then it's allowed. This will return a new *function* that you can execute. If somebody complained that *technically* `.replace` is a method, then *technically*, the return result of `.bind` is definitely not.

This is creative interpretation on many point but I still find it *a better answer* than `eval`.

Answer (score -1):

**split()** is a prototype function in JavaScript which can be called on a *string* and accepts a string *value* (and returns an array) e.g.`"hello world".split(" ")` will split the "hello world" string on spaces (i.e will return an array: `["hello", "world"]`

split() JS documentary:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

**join()** is a prototype function in JavaScript which can be called on an *array* and accepts a string *value* (and returns a string) e.g. `["my", "name", "is", "Sam"].join(" ")` will return `my name is Sam`

join() JS documentary:
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#:~:text=The%20join()%20method%20creates,returned%20without%20using%20the%20separator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#:%7E:text=The%20join()%20method%20creates,returned%20without%20using%20the%20separator).

Soo, **a combination of `split().join()` is similar to a replace function but is more reliable**

So split on the "_" character (`"1_22_333".split("_"`) will return `["1", "22", "333"]` and join("") on that array will return "122333"

```
const num = "1_22_333";
const newNum = Number(num.split("_").join(""))
```